# how to use find command for multiple file names?

Tags: bash, shell

I have to search for files with extension *.c or *.cpp or *.cc in a single find command using name. How to use an OR operator in find.?

`find . -name '*.c' OR '*.cpp' OR '*.cc'`

The exact syntax on how do i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group them with `\( \)` (the slash is just to escape from the shell).

`find . \( -iname bla -or -iname foo -or -name 'john dorian' \)`

Answer (score 2):

[Interestingly](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find)

```
find . -name '*.c' -or -name '*.cpp' -or -name '*.cc'
```

Comment: .c extension files are not recognized.